# Combining GroupBy and Count of items matching a criteria in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am struggling to figure out a LINQ statement to summarize data.  I am learning c# by developing a tool to help me clean up my duplicate files.  I already have a dictionary variable that is populated with file item information stored in fileResult which is defined as `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.  The List items include Path, FileHash, and FolderDupFileCount (among other items).

I have successfully used this LINQ expression to summarize all the distinct FileHash, assign a group id, and count all with the same hash.

```
var fileMD5Groups = fileResult.GroupBy(x => x.Value.FileHash).Select((x, xid) => 
                    new { x.Key, count = x.Distinct().Count(), id = xid + 1 }).ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z);
```

Now, I have the query below that works and it counts the number of files in the path.  I am trying to figure out how to modify this statement to count the files in this path that have duplicates elsewhere (for each Path, provide a count of the files in this Path that are duplicate)

```
           // Group by Path and Count the files in this path that have duplicates
           // fileResult contains a field called FileHash
            var folderDuplicateCount =
                from file in fileResult
                group file by file.Value.Path into g
                where g.Count() > 1
                select new { Path = g.Key, FolderDupFileCount = g.Count() };
            
            // Convert to dictionary
            Dictionary<string, int> dupResults = folderDuplicateCount
                                                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Path, x => x.FolderDupFileCount);
```

I imagine this is simple for a skilled person, which I am trying to become, so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
Below is the complete method that I am using.

```
public static bool UpdateFileHashResults(Dictionary<string, FolderItem> folderResult, Dictionary<string, FileItem> fileResult)
        {
            var fileMD5Groups = fileResult.GroupBy(x => x.Value.FileHash).Select((x, xid) => new { x.Key, count = x.Distinct().Count(), id = xid + 1 }).ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z);

           // Group by Path and Count the files in this path which have the
           // same FileHash that are in other Path's
           // fileResult contains a field called FileHash
            var folderDuplicateCount =
                from file in fileResult
                group file by file.Value.Path into g
                where g.Count() > 1
                select new { Path = g.Key, FolderDupFileCount = g.Count() };
            Dictionary<string, int> dupResults = folderDuplicateCount.ToDictionary(x => x.Path, x => x.FolderDupFileCount);
            timeItLinq.Stop();
            timeItAssignValue.Restart();
            foreach (var file in fileResult.ToList())
            {
                var ik = file.Key;
                var ivMD5Hash = file.Value.FileHash;
                var fResult = fileResult[ik];
                var ivFileFolder = file.Value.Path;

                fResult.FileHashGroupID = fileMD5Groups[ivMD5Hash].id;
                fResult.FileHashCount = fileMD5Groups[ivMD5Hash].count;
                
                if (RS.FoldersFound)
                {
                    var folResult = folderResult[ivFileFolder];
                    fResult.FolderID = folResult.FolderID;
                    var dupCount = 0;
                    if (dupResults.ContainsKey(ivFileFolder))
                    {
                        dupCount = dupResults[ivFileFolder];
                    }

                    fResult.FolderDupFileCount = dupCount;
                    folResult.FolderDupFileCount = dupCount;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Now, `var fileResult = fileListing.FindFiles(fileList)` is the fist assignment, using the interface:

```
public interface IFileListing
    {
        Dictionary<string, FileItem> FindFiles(IEnumerable<string> files);
    }
```

For the folder results `var folderResult =FolderListing.FindFolders(folderPaths);` and uses the interface below.

```
    public interface IFolderListing
    {
        Dictionary<string, FolderItem> FindFolders(IEnumerable<string> folders);
    }
```

**Desired result:**
I'm trying to get results that are grouped by Path, and with a count of the files in this folder that have FileHash's identical to files in other Paths.  So, if the path has 10 files, and 2 of the files the same hash as a file from another Path, then the result for this Path for the .FolderDupFileCount should be 2.

I hope this provides more clarity on the result.

Comment: `x.Value.FileHash` is not a reference to a `List<T>` or `List<T>` member: what is the type of `fileResult` again?

Comment: ifileResult is defined as `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Comment: Then how does `x.Value.FileHash` not cause a compilation error? Not to mention `file.Value.Path`?

Comment: I have added an Edit to show more of the code and hope it explains it.  Now, I am not an expert at C#, but I can confirm that this code run without compilation errors, and it does provide results, which counts all the files in a path.

Comment: From your code: `Dictionary<string, FileItem> fileResult` - so not `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` at all. Types are paramount in C# - getting them right, using them correctly and knowing what they do informs most C# programming.

Comment: So in `fileMD5Groups` you are computing `Distinct()` on `x` (note: using a good lambda name is much better, such as `kvg` (key value group) or `frg` (file result group)). Since we now know `fileResult` is `Dictionary<string, FileItem>` then we know that `x` is a `KeyValuePair` which is a `struct` and the documentation tells us has no `IEquality` implementation which means equality is defined as pointing to the same objects in the `Key` and `Value` fields. This is unlikely to be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning a bit more about linq and some more trial and error, I found a solution that works.  Thanks NetMage for the questions and comments that helped me think through the problem.  I also changed my lambda names as suggested, but not sure if it is entirely consistent.

I am posting the solution that works; however I feel the code doesn't look that elegant and there are maybe better ways of doing some tasks in this method.  ***Any suggestions for streamlining improving this method would be helpful for me to develop good programming standards and habits.***

For the solution, I deleted the `folderDuplicateCount` query and modified the `dupResults` query.  Since my `fileResult` dictionary has `Path` as a field I used this dictionary instead of the `folderResult` variable.

Now, the modified `dupResults` provides the correct results.  I also added two additional calculated fields `DupFilesHash = string.Concat(frg.Select(fvg => fvg.FileHash))` and `id = frgId + 1`.  These fields are helpers to update fields in my dictionaries and are assigned under specific conditions.  `DupFileHash` is the concatenated hashes of the files in this Path, that have duplicates in other paths.  This hash string is then re-hashed to provide a unique fingerprint representing these duplicates which can be used to locate/match duplicates elsewhere.

The biggest problem that I couldn't figure out was after the first `.GroupBy(frg => frg.Path)`, it seemed I couldn't access the other value fields.  I came across an example showing the `frg.Select(fvg => fvg.FileHash)` and then the light went on and I learned something new.

```
public static bool UpdateFileHashResults(Dictionary<string, FolderItem> folderResult, Dictionary<string, FileItem> fileResult)
        {
            // List of file hashes with a count of files with identical hashes
            var fileMD5Groups = fileResult.FileItemDictionaryToList()
                .GroupBy(kvg => kvg.FileHash)
                .Select((kvg, kvgId) => new { kvg.Key, 
                    count = kvg.Distinct().Count(), 
                    id = kvgId + 1 })
                .ToDictionary(krg => krg.Key, kvg => kvg);

            // List of all folders and a count of the number of files in this folder 
            // that have the same file hash in another folder(s)
            var dupResults = fileResult.FileItemDictionaryToList()
                .Where(frg => fileMD5Groups[frg.FileHash].count > 1)
                .GroupBy(frg => frg.Path)
                .Select((frg, frgId) => new { Path = frg.Key, 
                    NumberOfFilesWithDuplicates = frg.Count(), 
                    DupFilesHash = string.Concat(frg.Select(fvg => fvg.FileHash)), 
                    id = frgId + 1})
                .ToDictionary(frg => frg.Path, fvg => fvg);
          
            // Loop over all files and back load values into folder and file results dictionaries
            timeItAssignValue.Restart();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, FileItem> file in fileResult.ToList())
            {
                string ik = file.Key;
                string ivMD5Hash = file.Value.FileHash;
                FileItem fResult = fileResult[ik];
                string ivFileFolder = file.Value.Path;
                int fileHashCount = fileMD5Groups[ivMD5Hash].count;

                fResult.FileHashGroupID = fileMD5Groups[ivMD5Hash].id;
                fResult.FileHashCount = fileHashCount;

                if (RS.FoldersFound)
                {
                    FolderItem folResult = folderResult[ivFileFolder];
                    fResult.FolderID = folResult.FolderID;
                    int dupCount = 0;
                    int dupID = 0;
                    string dupFilesHash = "";
                    
                    if (dupResults.ContainsKey(ivFileFolder) && fileHashCount> 1)
                    {
                        dupCount = dupResults[ivFileFolder].NumberOfFilesWithDuplicates;
                        dupID = dupResults[ivFileFolder].id;
                        dupFilesHash= dupResults[ivFileFolder].DupFilesHash;
                        dupFilesHash = HashTool.MD5StringHash(dupFilesHash);
                            
                    }

                    fResult.FolderDupFileCount = dupCount;
                    folResult.FolderDupFileCount = dupCount;
                    fResult.FolderDupFileCountID = dupID;
                    folResult.FolderDupFileCountID = dupID;
                    fResult.FolderDupFilesHash = dupFilesHash;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```